# how to find if two elements can span a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, matlab

My goal is to solve a really simple linear algebra problem , "To check whether if two elements can span a whole vector space"

I could see that is easy to find basis for  matrices space but how about a space of all real polynomials of a degree at most two , I guess a way to check this is to consider if linear combination of elements given can produce the  space , but I think that's a lot of calculation for a simple problem

Anyway the question is here :
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIF0Y.png)

Well in this case it's easy to bring a Counterexample as the book suggests ,How ever I want to solve the problem using MATLAB so it can be solved in different situation

Thanks in advance (any other method to solve the problem or simply to check if the statement is true or false is highly appreciated)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The only way two vectors might fail to span a two dimensional space is if one is a multiple of the other, which ought to be easy to test.  Is that what you are asking?  Note that the space of polynomials of degree $≤2$ is three dimensional.

Comment: There are not vectors rather a polynomial with degree of most two , and the space is a all real polynomial with degree of most two, and if what you are saying is true 'p(x)' and 'q(x)' should span the space but linear combination of those can't generate 1  @lulu

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.  The space of polynomials of degree at most $2$ with real coefficients is a vector space under the obvious operations.  It has dimension $3$, a basis is given by $\{1,x,x^2\}$.  It can not be spanned by two vectors.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Thanks I will edit the post for sure ,the problem is this is before that we are introduce to dimensions , so I can't  use that definition of dimension , let alone using it to answer the question @lulu

Comment: So, show that you can't get $1$ in the span.  For example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ has dimension 3, so for sure two vectors can't generate it. Anyway, it's easy to see that for example $x$ doesn't belong to the span of $1+2x+x^2$ and $2+x^2$: indeed you have to find $a$ and $b$ (in the field on which the vector space is built, so in this case in $\mathbb{R}$ ) such that $a(1+2x+x^2)+b(2+x^2)=x$ (equality here is identity between polynomials),then you get $a+2b+2ax+(a+b)x^2=x$, and so $a+2b=0$, $2a=1$ and $a+b=0$, that is clearly impossible.

Comment: thanks , should coefficients (a & b)  be taken from the field of the space ?